# React-Native App that connects to Metamask Wallet

Tags: metamask, walletconnect

I am working on a project that just needs to retrieve the user's public address from the Metamask wallet into my project app. Can I get some help regarding this issue? I have tried the official Metamask SDK but it gets stuck on the wallet and does not return to the app with a connect wallet prompt as it shows in the example.
I have tried Implementing the same using WalletConnect but couldn't get it to work as well. It would be extremely helpful if someone could share an example. Thank you.
Added below is a snippet of the code used to connect Metamask using the Metamask SDK.

```
const connect = async () => { 
  try { 
  console.log('Connection Started:::::::'); 
   const result = await ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'}); 
   console.log('RESULT', result?.[0]); 
    setAccount(result?.[0]); 
    getBalance(); 
    } catch (e) { console.log('ERROR', e); } 
};
```

Comment: Hey, can you show the code you are using?

Comment: Using Metamask SDK: const connect = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Connection Started:::::::');
      const result = await ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
      console.log('RESULT', result?.[0]);
      setAccount(result?.[0]);
      getBalance();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERROR', e);
    }
  };

Comment: The Declarations are as follows: 

const sdk = new MetaMaskSDK({
  openDeeplink: link => {
    Linking.openURL(link);
  },
  timer: BackgroundTimer,
  dappMetadata: {
    name: 'React Native Test Dapp',
    url: 'example.com',
  },
});

const ethereum = sdk.getProvider();

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);

Comment: It is quite difficult to read, would be possible that you edit your question add into it with code format?

Comment: I've include the forst code snoppet, so you can see how it works

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you @donoso.eth I have added the changes. Can you help me with the connection issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code snippet to use wallet connect to get wallet address:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Button, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useWalletConnect } from "@walletconnect/react-native-dapp";

export default function WalletConnectExperience() {
  const connector = useWalletConnect();

  const connectWallet = React.useCallback(() => {
    return connector.connect();
  }, [connector]);

  return (
    <>
      {!connector.connected ? (
        <Button onPress={connectWallet} label="Connect wallet" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Text>{connector.accounts[0]}</Text>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Metamask sdk refrences: https://c0f4f41c-2f55-4863-921b-sdk-docs.github.io/guide/metamask-sdk-js/metamask-sdk-react-native.html